# Missing observable methods RxJS 5.0.0-beta.0

Tags: http, typescript, browserify, angular, rxjs

I'm having a problem using RxJS with Angular 2. Most of methods suggested from Typescript definition file are not defined on my Observable object like...

[image]

[image]

then I figured out, that methods does not exists on the Observable prototype.

[image]

**I know a lot of things changed from version 4 to 5,so do I miss something?**

Browserify added it for me...
[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Without seeing your actual code, I can't tell you exactly what to add to fix it.

But the general problem is this: RxJS 5 is not included with Angular 2 any longer now that it has entered the Beta stage.  You will need to import either the operator(s) you want, or import them all.  The import statements looks like this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; // imports just map
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap'; // just mergeMap
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap'; // just switchMap
import {delay} from 'rxjs/operator/delay'; // just delay
```

or like

```
import 'rxjs/Rx'; // import everything
```

To determine the path to your desired module, look at the [source tree](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/tree/5.0.0-beta.0/src/). Every import with `add` will add properties to `Observable` or `Observable.prototype`. Without `add`, you'd need to do `import {foo} from 'rxjs/path/to/foo'`.

You will also need to make sure that RxJS is being brought into the project correctly.  Something like this would go into your index.html file:

```
System.config({
    map: {
        'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs' // this tells the app where to find the above import statement code
    },
    packages: {
        'app': {defaultExtension: 'js'}, // if your app in the `app` folder
        'rxjs': {defaultExtension: 'js'}
    }
});
System.import('app/app'); // main file is `app/app.ts`
```

If you use [Webpack to build the Angular 2 app like in this Github project](https://github.com/michaeloryl/angular2-bootstrap4-oauth2-webpack) (like I did), then you don't need that `System` stuff and the imports should do it.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, in Angular 2.0 you have to include the operators/observables you need.

I do it like this:

```
import 'rxjs/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/operator/delay';
import 'rxjs/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/observable/interval';
import 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin';
import 'rxjs/observable/fromEvent';
```

However, you also need to configure this in System.js

```
System.config({
            defaultJSExtensions: true,
            paths: {
                'rxjs/observable/*' : './node_modules/rxjs/add/observable/*.js',
                'rxjs/operator/*' : './node_modules/rxjs/add/operator/*.js',
                'rxjs/*' : './node_modules/rxjs/*.js'
            }
        });
```

Here is working code: https://github.com/thelgevold/angular-2-samples

Answer (score 1):

I have a JSPM setup in my project, so adding rxjs to the path section was not enough.

jspm added the following to my SystemJS configuration (map section):

```
"npm:angular2@2.0.0-beta.6": {
  "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
  "es6-promise": "npm:es6-promise@3.1.2",
  "es6-shim": "npm:es6-shim@0.33.13",
  "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
  "reflect-metadata": "npm:reflect-metadata@0.1.2",
  "rxjs": "npm:rxjs@5.0.0-beta.0",
  "zone.js": "npm:zone.js@0.5.14"
},
```

So if you use jspm make sure you remove the rxjs mapping above, otherwise some rxjs files will be loaded twice, once via jspm_packages and once via node_modules.