# Cancel observable after first time - Angular2, TypeScript, rxjs/Observable

Tags: typescript, observable, rxjs5

I’m doing a check for existing login at start of app which I want only once.  How do we cancel that subscription after the first time?  I tried take(1) but that doesn't seem to work.

```
this.auth.getUserData().take(1).subscribe(data => { // the take(1) doesn't work
  console.log('Firebase responded with success.');
  this.rootPage = TabsPage;
 }, err => {
  console.log('Firebase responded with error.', err);
  this.rootPage = LoginEmailPage;
 }
);
```

Comment: Can you please advise what you mean with "doesn't work"? Does it actually call your subscription handler more than once? Why do you want to cancel the subscription? Is it not sufficient if the observable completes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `first()` instead of `take(1)`

Depending on your imports at the module level, you may want to add an import for the **first** operator

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first'
```

While this does not actually cancel the subscription, it completes the observation which is which I believe is what was meant.

EDIT: adding the explicit way of cancelling the subscription as originally requested by the OP

The result of .subscribe(...) will return a handler to the subscription. You can use that handle to explicitly cancel the subscription and the code would look like this:

```
let subscription = this.auth.getUserData().take(1).subscribe(data => { // the take(1) doesn't work
  console.log('Firebase responded with success.');
  this.rootPage = TabsPage;
  subscription.unsubscribe();
 }, err => {
  console.log('Firebase responded with error.', err);
  this.rootPage = LoginEmailPage;
 }
);
```

While it feels wrong to explicitly cancel the subscription in this case, a common pattern is to create the subscription within `ngOnInit()` or based on post init events, and cancel pending subscriptions within the `ngOnDestroy()`.

Comment: `first()` and `take(1)` are identical behaviors

Comment: Then I do not understand what the OP is looking for. I will edit my answer to specify specifically how to cancel the subscription.

Comment: The answer is about right and the same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548924/missing-observable-methods-rxjs-5-0-0-beta-0?noredirect=1&lq=1  With a recent angular version, the rxjs imports have to be specified.